# Does this code in C fall into the Undefined Behavior category?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, increment, undefined-behavior

`a` is an array, `foo` is a function, and `i` is an `int`.

```
a[++i] = foo(a[i-1], a[i]);
```

Would the code above, have an **Undefined Behavior**?

The array indices `++i`, `i-1` and `i`, are guaranteed to be in the array range.

Comment: What makes you think it might have an undefined behavior?

Comment: @litelite Where is the sequence point in your opinion? What is the execution orde?

Comment: @PeterJ Sequence point?

Comment: @litelite Yes the point where the ++ will be evaluated. Before foo or after?

Comment: Undefined because we don't know whether or not a[++i] will be evaluated before or aver a[i] or a[i - 1] In other words, we don't know the value of i.

Comment: @PeterJ Well, i did not read the standard about that before so i did not knew. But Vlad seems to have the answer.

Comment: @litelite if you do not know why do you comment this ironic way : `What makes you think it might have an undefined behavior?`. The question is what made you think that is not

Comment: It's actually tricky because *function calls* **are** sequence points (as well as returning from library functions). It doesn't help here because assignment is unsequenced, so you don't know when exactly the function call happens relative to incrementing `i` in `a[++i]`.

Comment: Perhaps if you think it is ub I would think it is a good idea to rewrite the code

Comment: @EdHeal that's what I'm going to do, It's just that code like this one is more compact and cleaner.

Comment: What is a extra line of code? Especially when all readers can read it without the need to scratch their head? Surely cleaner code is what all understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is undefined, but it's not because of the modification of the same object twice between two sequence points but it is UB because the side effect on `i` is unsequnced relative to the value computation of `a[i-1]` and `a[i]` using `i`.

§6.5-p(2):

> **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to** either a different side effect on the same scalar object or **a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined**. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>

For example, expression

```
a[i++] = i;
```

invokes undefined behavior. Same is true for

```
a[++i] = foo(a[i-1], a[i]);
```

Comment: Nice simplified example.  Clarifies application of identical rules to slightly more complicated statement.

Comment: what about this one : `i++;`  `a[i] = foo(a[i-2], a[i-1]);`  ?

Comment: @BiteBytes; That's the correct way to do this and have defined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators):

> Semantics
>
> 3  ...The evaluations of the operands are **unsequenced**.

Thus this statement

```
a[++i] = foo(a[i-1], a[i]);
```

results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Just evaluation of operands being unsequenced doesn't mean it is UB. Every function call has its argument evaluation unsequenced.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In the shown example it is the reason for the undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow; You are right in the shown example "unsequenced" is the reason for UB but not alone, along with modification of `i`. That's what Ajay is trying to say.

Comment: @hacks It is clear without any comment. It is the reason for the question.

Comment: I always hear this notion of "sequencing" would you explain it furthermore please?

Comment: Not exactly. The main issue here is that the standard does not specify when the increment takes place, only that `++i` evaluates to `i+1`. Even if `++i` was guaranteed to be evaluated first, this would still raise UB.

Comment: More specifically, this is not about order of evaluation, but side effects.

Comment: @giusti It is about whether the evaluations of the left and right operands are sequenced or not.

Comment: @giusti And there is clear written in the Standard according to the increment: "See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for information on
constraints, types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of operations on pointers."

Comment: Does "unsequenced" mean there is no sequence point between each expression?

Comment: @giusti If the evaluation of sub-expressions  is unsequenced then there can not be a sequence point between them.:)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is Undefined Behavior.

Not because one is not allowed to read and write to the same variables between 2 sequence points but because of the rule that

> Between any two sequence points, all the reads of a variable should directly be used in the computing the result of the write to the same variable.

Here the write to `i` is `i++`. The read on the same variable is in the arguments. 
Although function call is a sequence point, the assignment isn't. So evaluation of array index can happen before evaluation of RHS.

The read on `i` in `foo(a[i-1], a[i])` doesn't directly contribute to the write and hence it is UB.

the relevant parts of the C99 standard are 6.5 Expressions, §2

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. **Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Assignment is sequenced after computation of the value to be stored, but the determination of what object is assigned and, for compound-assignment operators, the determination of its initial value, aren't.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is undefined because the expressions `a[++i]`, `a[i-1]`, and `a[i]` are unsequenced relative to each other.

Chapters and verses:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2     **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
> on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object, the behavior is undefined.** If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
> effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
> ...
> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
> ...
> 10     **There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual
> arguments but before the actual call.** Every evaluation in the calling function (including
> other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
> execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to
> the execution of the called function.<sup>94)</sup>
> ...
> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> ...
> 3     An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An
> assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>111)</sup> but is not
> an lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
> after lvalue conversion. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
> sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands. **The evaluations of
> the operands are unsequenced.**
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```
>
> ...
> 94) In other words, function executions do not ‘‘interleave’’ with each other
> ...
> 111) The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is not required to, even
> when the object has volatile-qualified type.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>