# What's the consequence of a sequence-point "immediately before a library function returns"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sequence-points

In [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45803172/2371524), some code was shown to have *undefined behavior*:

```
a[++i] = foo(a[i-1], a[i]);
```

because even though the actual *call* of `foo()` is a *sequence point*, the *assignment* is *unsequenced*, so you don't know whether the function is called after the side-effect of `++i` took place or before that.

Thinking further about this, the *sequence point* at a function call only guarantees that *side effects* from evaluating the function arguments are carried out once the function is entered, e.g.

```
int y = 1;
int func1(int x) { return x + y; }
int main(void)
{
    int result = func1( y++ ); // guaranteed to be 3
}
```

But looking at the standard, there's also **§7.1.4 p3** (in the chapter about the standard library):

> There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns.

My question here is: What's the consequence of this paragraph? Why does it only concern *library functions* and what kind of code would actually rely on that?

Simple ideas like (nonsensical code to follow)

```
errno = 0;
long result = ftell(file) * errno;
```

would still be undefined as this time, the *multiplication* is unsequenced. I'm looking for an example that makes use of this special guarantee §7.1.4 p3 makes for *library functions*.

---

Regarding the suggested duplicate, [Sequence point after a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15637678/2371524), this is indeed closely related and I found it before asking this question. It's not a duplicate, because

- it asks about normative text stating there *is* a sequence point immediately after a `return`, without asking about the consequences when there is one.
- it only mentions the special rule for library functions **this** question is about, without further elaborating on it.

Consequently, my questions here are not answered over there. The accepted answer uses a return value in an unsequenced expression (in this case an *addition*) and explains how the result depends on the sequencing of this addition, only finding that *if you knew* the sequencing of the addition, the whole result would be defined with a sequence point immediately after `return`. It doesn't show an example of code that is actually defined because of this rule, and it doesn't say anything about how/why *library functions* are special.

Comment: "standard disclaimer": If you downvote because I miss something "obvious", please leave a comment to point it out, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequence point after a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637678/sequence-point-after-a-return-statement)

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I checked that one, it's closely related but doesn't answer **this** question. Although the special library function rule is mentioned there, there's no example for code where this rule actually has any effect.

Comment: Practical use of this statement is when multithreading is used in a program.

Comment: @haccks I guess there must be something else, as the same paragraph is already found in C99.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Library functions don't have the code that implements them covered by the standard (they might not even be implemented in C). The standard only specifies their behaviour.  So the provision about `return` statements does not apply to implementation of library functions.

The purpose of this clause (in combination with there being a sequence point on entry of a library function) is to say that any side-effects of the library functions are sequenced either before or after any other evaluations that might be in the code which calls the library function.

So the example in your question is not undefined behaviour (unless the multiplication overflows!): the read of `errno` is either sequenced before or after the modification by `ftell`, it's unspecified which.

Comment: Ahh, the subtle difference between "undefined" and "unspecified" ... I tend to use them too sloppily I guess. Thanks so far! (isn't your example undefined for something completely different: signed overflow?)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I changed my answer to use your example, in my original example I don't think there was signed overflow but if there was then it would detract from my point so your example is better anyway

Comment: Well, there was, `strtol` would have returned `LONG_MAX` and `ERANGE` is positive :) At least, your first paragraph explains very logically why library functions are "special" here, thanks and uv'd :)