# Why is there a sequence point immediately before library functions?

Tags: c, function, sequence-points, c-standard-library

Standard says that:

> *There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns. C17dr § 7.1.4 3.*

I know that there is a sequence point before actual call and after return statement (due to semicolon if there is another reason please let me know) but i couldn't understand the sentence above. Could anyone please explain this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the consequence of a sequence-point "immediately before a library function returns"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814572/whats-the-consequence-of-a-sequence-point-immediately-before-a-library-functio)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't understand this "Library functions don't have the code that implements them covered by the standard (they might not even be implemented in C)" part of the answer.

Comment: @UlaşSezgin what part of that quote didn't you understand?  It answers your question

Comment: I think the point is that we know there is a sequence point after a `return` statement, but we don't have any guarantee that a library function actually contains a `return` statement, or any statements at all, since it may not be written in C.

Answer (score 4):

It means you can write code like `t = sqrt(t)`. It would be *really* annoying if you couldn't.

And the behaviour of the above would be undefined if the C standard didn't guarantee that the functions had sequencing points in prior to their returning.

Note that C standard library functions might be hardcoded by the compiler - so this is an important consideration. It also adds extra protection for the user of a standard library implementation that might implement some functions as macros (which is permitted subject to a plethora of rules).

(Note that the rule has been carried over to C++).

Comment: Now I'm curious whether there are other ways in which a library function might not act exactly "as if" implemented by a C language function definition.

Comment: Okay, but  I think, we can write this code thanks to other sequence point rules. Can't we ?

Comment: @aschepler I imagine things like setjmp and thread creation functions definitely do not operate as something that can be implemented in pure C.

Comment: @aschepler: It also guards against functions implemented as macros (although it could be a tautology). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029568/defining-c-functions-in-the-c-standard-library-as-macros#:~:text=The%20rules%20of%20the%20standard,also%20implemented%20as%20a%20macro.

Comment: I am at my happiest when the compiler does hardcode standard lib stuff.  Please give me my inline intrinsic functions per platform without needing LTO to make the function calls go away...