# While loop does not want to work properly in C

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I want to store some values in an array and want the array to stop storing values when the user inputs 0
So i have this code :

```
int numbers[100];
int i = 0;

do

{

        printf("Enter the %d value : ", (i+1) );
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);

        i++;
}while (numbers[i] != 0);
```

But it does not work, i spent like 2 hours on this.
Help please
Thanks

Comment: missing semicolon after `i++`

Comment: missing semicolon in the first line. Post [MCVE] and a proper description of what is not working.

Comment: That `i++` means you're repeatedly examining uninitialized data in your do-while condition, btw. Even if you fix the syntax, you're program still invokes *undefined behavior*. You also make no attempt at validating `scanf` actually *worked* (it has a return value for a reason; [check your documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). That's a buried conditional bug just waiting to happen.

Comment: You write the user value to `numbers[i]` (eg `numbers[2]`), then increment `i` (eg `3`) and test `numbers[i] /* new i! */` (eg `numbers[3]`) which is no longer what the user wrote.

Comment: Pmg, Eugene, Whozcraig thanks for the comments. 1.Actually i put those semicolons in my code, i just made a mistake while recopying; 2. What was not working that the table does not want to stop storing values when i input 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They work perfect.

But you increase `i` before checking the condition.

Try `}while (numbers[i++] != 0);` and remove `i++` in the previous line.

Comment: P__J__ - you're correct, but there are other problems with the OP's code, too.  SUGGESTION: why not give a complete example?

Comment: I tried it, and it's working now. Thanks

Comment: But i don't really understand it, can you explain how the "while ( number[i++] )" work ?

Comment: because i++ is increased after the check

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @P__J__'s answer, this works:

```
int numbers[100];
int i = 0;

do
{
    printf("Enter the %d value : ", (i+1) );
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);

}while (numbers[i++] != 0);
```

There were some missing semicolons, but the major issue is incrementing `i` before using it in the `while` condition. `i++` returns the original value of `i`, and then increments it.

Comment: Q: is the "while()" expression [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803172/does-this-code-in-c-fall-into-the-undefined-behavior-category.  I *believe* it's OK, because I believe "!=" introduces a sequence point.  Q: Have you tried it?  Does it work?

Comment: afaik, it would be undefined behavior if we had something like `numbers[i++] != i`. But this does not appear to be undefined behavior, and it works. **EDIT:** If you use `numbers[i++] != i` and compile with flags `-Wall -Werror`, you get an unsequenced modification error. But using `numbers[i++] != 0` does not throw an error.

Comment: Beautiful - that's what I thought.  Thank you for confirming :)

Comment: It's finally working, thanks tejgop. I just removed the "i++" that was before the condition test and put it in the condition test itself (while number[i++])

Comment: But i don't really understand it, can you explain how the "while ( number[i++] )" work ?

Comment: Suppose `i=0`. If you do `number[i]`, it evaluates to `number[0]`. If you do `number[++i]`, it *first* increments it, resulting in `number[1]`. But we did `number[i++]` which first evaluates to `number[0]`, and *then* increments to `i=1`.